# CSS: changing the color of a bullet in a list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a problem with changing the color of a bullet in a list.

So I have a list inside a `<nav>` tag in my HTML file:

```html
<nav id="top-menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="">Home</a> </li>
        <li><span> <a href="">Products</a> </span></li>
        <li> <a href="">Statistics</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Countries</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Settings</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Contacts</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

So as you can see my `<nav>` tag has an `id="top-menu"`. And one more thing:

```
<li><span> <a href="">Products</a> </span></li>
```

Here you can see that I put a `<span>` tag inside my bullet.

Here is my CSS file:

```css
nav#top-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: #696969;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #696969;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: #696969 solid 2px;
}


#top-menu ul li a:hover { border-bottom: #FFFFFF solid 2px; }
```

Then I add this:

```css
#top-menu ul li span {
    color: black;
}
```

The problem is it doesn't change anything.

In other words for now every bullet in my navigation menu is white but I want to make "Products" black.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this way**

```
#top-menu ul li   span  a{
    color: black;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/cBvga/)**

Comment: it doesn't change anything

Comment: Only changes Product to black :)

Comment: @Michael Did you see the `a` after the span in this suggestion?  It is working for me.  The only thing this is changing is the text color of the word 'product'.

Answer (score 1):

Usually such modifications are done using a class instead of altering the html markup structure. I added a class "highlight" to the item:

http://jsfiddle.net/bvedE/1/

HTML markup:

```
<nav id="top-menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="">Home</a> </li>
        <li class="highlight"> <a href="">Products</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Statistics</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Countries</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Settings</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Contacts</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code:

```
#top-menu ul li.highlight * {
    color: black;
}
```

With a slight modification at the bottom of the css you get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/QZD5d/

CSS

```
nav#top-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: #696969;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #696969;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: #696969 solid 2px;
}


#top-menu ul li a:hover { border-bottom: #FFFFFF solid 2px; }

#top-menu ul li span a{
    color:black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
#top-menu ul li span a{
    color: black !important;
}
```